# Check discord bot shard (connection) status

Tags: discord, discord.js

Using discord.js (v12), is there a way to check a shard's status? For example, "reconnecting", or "resuming". I could not find a way to do this, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use shards, but in my bot I have the debug log enabled:

```js
bot.on("debug", info => console.log(info));
```

This gives a heartbeat for each shard every minute and tells you if and when the shard connects & how many servers it's able to connect to. Even without different shards for my bot I think it's pretty handy and it may help you.

Comment: Does the info include the status such as "reconnecting" or "resuming"?